# Order results by results from a different table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to have something like this in one query,

Count how many likes a certain ID has in `image_likes` and then order results from `images` descending by how many likes they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `images`
ORDER BY
    (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `image_likes` WHERE `image_id`=images.`id`) ASC
```

(I have of course made up field names, but this format should work)

If possible, you might want to change the way the system works so that you can just read the total likes from a field name rather than doing a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
select imageid, count(imageid) from image_likes 
Group by imageid
Order by Count(imageid) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) as count from image_likes il WHERE ID = i.ID)         
FROM images) tbl ORDER BY COUNT
```

untested